# when I try to export Deployment Features In Capella studio security problem occurred

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

[problem that appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2gEU.png)
when I try to export Deployment Features for my plugins In Capella studio security problem occurred  .

I tried to disable security manager but didn't find it.

I use JDK-17 and Capella-studio 6.0.0.

Comment: This is a message about `java.lang.SecurityManager` which should not be used anymore.

Comment: How can I disable it?

Comment: You don't "disable" it. The message means some code is using the `SecurityManager` class and should be rewritten not to use SecurityManager.